# Asterisk Integration with Symfony2 application

Tags: symfony, asterisk, voip, telephony, asteriskami

I'm new about Asterisk, it's already installed and I have all host details, what I need is how to use Asterisk in my symfony2 web application; Someone have an idea or he worked on this before?

**EDIT**

Here is the list what I should do in my web application:

1. Create a stasis application
2. Listen for a call.
3. Play the “beep” sound which is already installed on the asterisk server.
4. Allow the user to enter a US formatted phone number.
5. Create a method to validate the phone number.
6. Hangup.

**EDIT 1**

I start by that small code in my controller :

```
use Pastum\Component\PAMI\Client\Client;

/* These are (in order) the options we can pass to PAMI client:
 *
 * The hostname or ip address where Asterisk AMI is listening
 * The scheme can be tcp:// or tls://
 * The port where Asterisk AMI is listening
 * Username configured in manager.conf
 * Password configured for the above user
 * Connection timeout in milliseconds
 * Read timeout in milliseconds
 */
 $options = array(
'host' => '127.0.0.1',
'scheme' => 'tcp://',
'port' => 9999,
'username' => 'admin',
'secret' => 'mysecret',
'connect_timeout' => 10000,
'read_timeout' => 10000
);

$client = new Client($options);

// Open the connection
$client->open();

// Close the connection
$client->close();
```

But I do  not know what I can do in the view page or after connection?

And how I can execute needs commands with code?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Asterisk in a Symfony Application. How We've done it:

- custom class for connecting to AMI and executing needed commands, like originate a call, whisper, hangup or listen
- add as second db your asterisk db if it is required, generate entities.

The biggest problem for you will be how to transfer the sound, one way is to use flash.

Phone number validation - you will find a lot of solutions on GOOGLE.

More detailed instruction:

- Create a bundle for Asterisk, there create your entities and Asterisk Service Class
- You'll need a Controller - that will handle your requests and call the service. For example you have to hangup a call, you need an action in your controller and an action in your service. In controller you init the service and call hangup action from service that will hangup call.

  ```
  public function hangupAction(Request $request)
  {
      $asteriskService = // Get the asterisk service
      $asteriskService->hangup();

      return new JsonReponse();
  }
  ```

  // Code from the service

  ```
  public function hangup($agent)
  {
      fputs($this->getSocket(), "Action:Hangup\r\n");
      fputs($this->getSocket(),     "Channel:/^SIP/".$agent."-.*$/\r\n\r\n");
      fclose($this->getSocket());
  }
  ```

Comment: Hi, really that's what I need, but I'm really new in Asterisk and I don't know what I can do,the big problem is the front-end view, for now I know only how to login, so can you help a little with some real code or examples...

Comment: Ok and how to use this code in controller, in view side, I mean in twig page, I mean thay are something to do to see something like interface in view part do you get me?

Comment: You should make AJAX requests to that action and in dependence of response do something in your page using js.

Comment: Give me your skype and I will try to explain to you more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [AGI](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI), [AMI](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4817239) and [ARI](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=29395573) interface. They are language/platform agnostics way to communicate/integrate with asterisk from external application.

There are some great PHP libraries for asterisk exists as well.

[PAGI](http://marcelog.github.io/PAGI/index.html), [PAMI](http://marcelog.github.io/PAMI/index.html), [PHPARI](http://www.phpari.org/) etc.

All of these libraries are available via composer. You can use it with Symfony2 just like other PHP packages.

Comment: Yes I tried with PAMI and I do code of quickstart and then I have a message with success login, but I stop here, I found no more example or documentation, for example I have some php code but no html code to display what we need..., I need a complete real examples....

Comment: What you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this bundle https://github.com/ryzhov/asterisk-bundle, but it connect through  asterisk AMI interface (5038 tcp port) for request and event, not stasis.

code example here https://github.com/ryzhov/example-asterisk-ami

Comment: You should demonstrate how this lib helps the OP to deal with its problem.